# Not able to print all parameters in the REST object

Tags: java, rest, api

I have a student class with few fields. For some reason, I am not getting "created" object created in Student object. When i send GET call to receive information of all student objects, I see only first 4 parameters. It is missing created field missing. What am I missing?

In Student constructor I have defined "this.created = new Date();" to assign value to created field.

```
 public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String address;
    private String enrolledDepartment;
    private Date created;

    public Student() {          
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String departmentName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.enrolledDepartment = departmentName;
        this.created = new Date();
    }

   // Getter and setters of all fields
}
```

Resource class

```
@Path("/students")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StudentsResource {

    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

    @GET
    public List<Student> getProfiles() {
        return studentService.getAllStudents();
    }

    @POST
    public Student addProfile(Student profile) {
        return studentService.addProfile(profile);
    }
}
```

Service class

```
public class StudentService {

    private List<Student> students = DatabaseClass.getStudents();

    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return students; 
    }

    public Student addProfile(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
        return student;
    }
}
```

Database class

```
public class DatabaseClass {

    private static List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<Student> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public static List<Email> getEmails() {
        return emails;
    }
}
```

I am sending a POST request using following JSON

```
{
    "address": "Boston",
    "enrolledDepartment": "health",
    "firstName": "abc",
    "lastName": "pqr"
}
```

Comment: What framework are you using? My guess is that it calls the default constructor (with no args) then set the value, try setting created in the default constructor also. It should then be saved on creation and later overridden for an existing object.

Comment: The behavior depends on which library you are using, there are configurations to ignore null fields during the marshalling, not including null properties in the generated json

Comment: I am using jersey framework.

Comment: @semako your suggestion worked. How can I setup to use parameterized constructor instead of default constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the "default constructor":

```
 public Student() {
    this.created = new Date();          
 }
```

...the constructor, that you assume, is not called, thus `created` remains `null`.

or even:

```
// ...
private Date created = new Date();

public Student() {          
}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String departmentName){
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.address = address;
    this.enrolledDepartment = departmentName;
    //this.created = new Date();
}
```

(initialize it in the declaration.)